# Ways to implement step by step registration process in android

Tags: android

I want to create a step by step registration process.
User will input username first then click next to input email, next to input password ...next for some other info 
then finally click register.
When user click register, all data will be stored in the database.

I've been able to implement the registration process, but user has to fill the entire form in just one activity which looks
tiring.

I want a step by step registration. not whole registration in one activity.

This is the same method used in Instagram.

[image: ig]

[image: ig1]

[image: ig2]

How can I do this.??

Comment: 3 different `Activitiy`s..Isn't that the best way to do it?

Comment: I think that you have to use fragments.

Comment: "I want a step by step registration. not whole registration in one activity." - a step-by-step registration does not require multiple activities. A single activity can implement a step-by-step registration process. A common UI pattern for this is [the wizard](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/131?sort=created).

Comment: How do i pass the data through each activity to the final activity before storing in database.? @Lal

Comment: You can use `putExtra()` to share data beween `Intent`s..

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) for each step of the registration process since you will be replacing few content in the layout.

In addition, you could use Facebook or Google account for login instead of just asking the user to register again in your application, its usually a boring process.

Source: [Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started)

Comment: Can you recommend any tutorial on this (relating to step registration process using fragments).? Searched but couldn't find.

Comment: I think this is a gppd example: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/